# How can I get 100% height layout with a fixed sidebar?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I have a very classic layout, but strangly, I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

I have a fixed sidebar (15% width) and the content (85% width) side by side.

I'm giving 100% height to all containers.

```
<html>
<body>
 <did id="content">
   <div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">  
    <div class="content">
        <section class="category_intro">
```

The problem I'm facing is that in some pages, the sections in the .content container overlapse eadchother..and I don't see why.

When I inspect element, I can see that the pointer doesn't cover all the container

[image]

I tried clear both, overflow auto, deleting the 100% height property to all container one by one, stoped using flexbox..

Maybe is it because my sidebar have a fixed position ?

Is there a simple way to restore the flow after a fixed sidebar using flexbox for the content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, the best way of building layout is using [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). Applying `display:grid;` on the parent element of your 2 main elements and using `grid-template-columns: 15% 85%;` will do everything for you.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 85%;
}

aside {
  background-color: blue;
}

main {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <aside></aside>
  <main></main>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok Robinvrd, I accept your answer as grid system seems to be a good solution ! Thank you !